# Is there any known or near future way to shield a spacecraft traveling at $0.1c$ from micrometeorites and dust? Or even for $0.01c $?

Tags: speed-of-light, interstellar-matter

Question is in title, the following are mere thoughts/ideas to make it happen.
I was thinking at 5-10 layers of kevlar or other polycarbonates reinforced with carbon nanotubes and water added in between each layer to help slow down the particle. Once a breach is detected an inflatable drone could seal off the impact hole to prevent the water from floating away while other drones would repair the outside hull.
Would a large magnet inside the spacecraft be able to deflect the metallic dust or micrometeorites at the given speed ? 
Would high powered lasers coupled with a ultra fine radar system be the way to go? Literally blast out any dangerous particles.

Comment: Scott Manley put out a new video that has a bearing on this. [Smashing An Asteroid All The Way Through Planet Earth!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=simuXjzxlGI)

Answer (score 3):

Sure. You don't need anything complicated. Put a very large rock in front of your spacecraft and let the micrometeors hit that.

It isn't very practical because it takes a lot of energy to accelerate a large rock to 0.01 C. But then, it isn't practical to accelerate any spacecraft to that speed either.

Micrometeors do damage at speeds that spacecraft can reach. Armor of the kind you mention is being considered. See http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/how-do-you-shield-astronauts-and-satellites-from-deadly-micrometeorites-3911799/ But it is not intended for relativistic speeds.

Comment: How do you think [these considerations](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/) might bear on the rock's longevity?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance - Good old XKCD. The rock would of course survive much longer in deep space where there are very few molecules and micrometeors. You would only want a relativistic spacecraft if you were going to say another star. Over a very long distance, it would add up. So you still want a big one.

Answer (score 0):

` I am confident that some sort of electronically enabled shielding will be developed in the near future. I have often wondered if a very strong electromagnetic field could be of some benefit to deflect and shield spacecrafts.
I also liked the rock shielding ideas, a rock or synthetic dedicated sacrificial shielding craft cruising many Km ahead of the main ship could defeat most threats. A swarm of small inexpensive craft could fly 'point' for a cloud of particles etc.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/424124)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).